# Diferença entre textos com vários parágrafos no Mysql

Tags: mysql, select

Tenho dois campos na tabela (text) que recebem várias linhas (parágrafos) de informação, por exemplo:

```
CAMPO1
linha1
linha2
linha4
linha5

CAMPO2
linha1
linha2
linha3
linha4
```

Eu preciso verificar qual linha está em falta cruzando a informação dos dois de forma a que, olhando para o exemplo, eu consiga indicar que falta a `linha3` no `CAMPO1` e que falta a `linha5` no `CAMPO2`.

Tem solução para esta consulta?

Comment: Pode posta suas tabelas como estão? e alguns dados delas como vem e como deveria vim?

Answer (score 1):

Com uma simples consulta isto não é possível.

Você poderia, no entanto, implementar uma função ou procedimento para comparar os textos, mas não conheço e não encontrei um algoritmo de diferença de textos implementado para MySQL.

De qualquer forma, fazer isso na consulta não compensa. Seria melhor recuperar os textos da base e fazer uso de alguma biblioteca da sua linguagem ou ferramenta disponível no servidor para executar a comparação.

Se você precisa mesmo recuperar isso através de uma consulta, uma outra estratégia seria reformular a base de forma a armazenar cada linha do texto numa outra tabela separadamente. Então você poderia facilmente fazer uma query assim:

```
SELECT LINHA 
FROM TEXTO 
WHERE TEXTO.ID = 'id-texto-1' 
  AND TEXTO.LINHA NOT IN (
        SELECT LINHA 
        FROM TEXTO 
        WHERE TEXTO.ID = 'id-texto-2'
  )

UNION ALL

SELECT LINHA 
FROM TEXTO 
WHERE TEXTO.ID = 'id-texto-2' 
  AND TEXTO.LINHA NOT IN (
        SELECT LINHA 
        FROM TEXTO 
        WHERE TEXTO.ID = 'id-texto-1'
  )
```

A desvantagem disso é que as consultas não consideram a ordem das linhas, mas se não for um problema deve funcionar.

Daria ainda para criar uma função que converte o texto em uma tabela temporária se você não quiser gravar as linhas separadamente, mas isso vai deixar a consulta muito mais lenta e é um pouco complicado para implementar.